# Merging two different sized intersecting circles and finding the coordinates of a radius-weighted center

Tags: javascript, math, trigonometry

I'm working on a fun little simulation environment for circles. I cannot find an accurate way to combine two circles and find their center coordinate.

I set up an html canvas, then generate random coords on the plane along with a random sized radius. After every generation, I check for an intersection between every circle and every other circle. When circles intersect I want them to merge - making a circle with the combined surface area. Finding the coordinates of the new center is my issue.

I don't want to simply find the midpoint of the centers because that doesn't factor in the size of the circles. A humongous circle could be swayed by a tiny one, which doesn't make for a realistic simulation.

I've thought up what I think is a bad solution: multiplying the change in distance created by the midpoint formula by the ratio of the two circles radii, getting the angle of the resulting triangle, using trig to get the x and y difference, then adding that to the center of the larger circle and calling it a day.

Really have no clue if that is the right way to do it, so I wanted to ask people smarter than me.

Oh also here's a link to the repo on github:
[Circle Simulator](https://github.com/Jaywin2099/Circle-Simulator)

This is my first stackOverflow question so bear with me if I did something completely stupid. Thanks everyone!

```js
var dataForm = document.getElementById('dataForm');
var type = document.getElementById('type');
var dataMinRad = document.getElementById('dataMinRad');
var dataMaxRad = document.getElementById('dataMaxRad');
var phaseInterval = document.getElementById('phaseInterval');

//form on submit
const onDataSubmit = (e) => {
    if (e) e.preventDefault();
    
    //updates min and max radius
    minRadius = parseInt(dataMinRad.value);
    maxRadius = parseInt(dataMaxRad.value);

    //clears canvas
    c.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    //clears circles
    circles = [];

    //clears any previous interval
    clearInterval(phase);
    
    let generator = eval(type.value), data;

    //every one second this code is repeated
    phase = setInterval(() => {
        //gets the circle data from whatever generator is selected
        data = generator();

        //adds the new circle and draws it on the canvas if the data is good
        if (data) {
            circles.push(new Circle(data.x, data.y, data.rad));
            circles[circles.length - 1].draw();
        }
    }, parseInt(phaseInterval.value));
}

dataForm.addEventListener('submit', onDataSubmit);

    </script>
    <script>

//initializes global elements
var stage = document.getElementById('stage');
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var c = canvas.getContext('2d');

//sets width and height of canvas to that of the stage
canvas.setAttribute('width', stage.clientWidth);
canvas.setAttribute('height', stage.clientHeight);

class Circle {
    constructor (x, y, rad) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.rad = rad;
    }
    draw() {
        c.fillStyle = 'black';
        c.beginPath();
        c.arc(this.x, this.y, this.rad, 0, 2 * Math.PI, true);
        c.stroke();
    }
}

//variables
var circles = [];
var maxRadius = 100;
var minRadius = 1;
var phase;

const random = () => {
    //random coords and radius
    let x, y, rad;

    do {
        [x, y, rad] = [Math.round(Math.random() * canvas.width), Math.round(Math.random() * canvas.height), Math.ceil(Math.random() * (maxRadius - minRadius)) + minRadius];
    } while ((() => {
        for (let i in circles) {
            if (Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x - circles[i].x, 2) + Math.pow(y - circles[i].y, 2)) < rad + circles[i].rad) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    })()) //end while

    return { x: x, y: y, rad: rad};
}

const order = () => {
    //gets some random coords and sets the radius to max
    let [x, y, rad] = [Math.round(Math.random() * canvas.width), Math.round(Math.random() * canvas.height), maxRadius];

    //decreases the radius while the resulting circle still intercects any other circle
    while (rad >= minRadius && (() => {
        for (let i in circles) {
            if (Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x - circles[i].x, 2) + Math.pow(y - circles[i].y, 2)) < rad + circles[i].rad) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    })()) {
        rad--;
    }

    //only sends the radii that are greater than the minimum radius
    if (rad >= minRadius) return { x: x, y: y, rad: rad};
}

//the position changes must be weighted somehow
const agar = () => {
    //some looping control variables
    let i = 0, j = 1, noChange = true;

    //loops through the circles array in every circle until the noChange variable is false
    while (i < circles.length && noChange) {
        while (j < circles.length && noChange) {
            //checks if each circle is inside each other circle
            if (Math.sqrt(Math.pow(circles[i].x - circles[j].x, 2) + Math.pow(circles[i].y - circles[j].y, 2)) < circles[i].rad + circles[j].rad) {
                //copies the two circles
                let tempCircles = [circles[i], circles[j]];

                //splices the item closest to the end of the array first so that the position of the other doesn't shift after the splice
                if (i > j) {
                    circles.splice(i, 1);
                    circles.splice(j, 1);
                } else {
                    circles.splice(j, 1);
                    circles.splice(i, 1);
                }

                //radius of the two circles' surface area combined
                let rad = Math.sqrt(tempCircles[0].rad * tempCircles[0].rad + tempCircles[1].rad * tempCircles[1].rad);

                /*
                // method 1: the midpoint of the centers //

                let x = (tempCircles[0].x + tempCircles[1].x) / 2;
                
                let y = (tempCircles[0].y + tempCircles[1].y) / 2;

                */

                // method 2: the radius ratio weighted //

                let bigCircle, smallCircle;

                if (tempCircles[0].rad > tempCircles[1].rad) {
                    bigCircle = tempCircles[0];
                    smallCircle = tempCircles[1];
                } else {
                    bigCircle = tempCircles[1];
                    smallCircle = tempCircles[0];
                }

                //get the distance between the two circles
                let dist = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(bigCircle.x - smallCircle.x, 2) + Math.pow(bigCircle.y - smallCircle.y, 2));

                //gets the ratio of the two circles radius size
                let radRatio = smallCircle.rad / bigCircle.rad;

                //the adjusted hypot for the ratio
                dist = dist * radRatio;
                
                //the angle
                let theta = Math.atan2(smallCircle.y - bigCircle.y, smallCircle.x - bigCircle.x); // all hail atan2!

                //the new center coords
                let x = bigCircle.x + dist * Math.cos(theta);
                let y = bigCircle.y + dist * Math.sin(theta);

                circles.push(new Circle(x, y, rad));

                //change happened so the variable should be false
                noChange = false;

                /*
                
                -find the middle of the point
                -weigh it in the direction of teh biggest circle

                radius as the magnitude and [angle of the triangle created when the centers are connected] as the direction for both radii.

                find the point on each circle closest to the center of the other circle

                find those two points midpoint

                find the distance from that point to each of the centers

                those two distances are the magnitude of two new vectors with the same angels as before

                add those two vectors

                is there really not a freaking easier way?
                
                */

                /*
                try this:

                -get the distance between the centers.
                -multiply that by the ratio
                -get the angle
                -use that angle and that hypot to find the x and y
                -add the x and y to the bigger circles centerr

                */
            }
            j++;
        }
        i++;
        j = i + 1;
    }
    
    //if there was no change
    if (noChange) {
        //random coords and radius size
        let x = Math.round(Math.random() * canvas.width),
            y = Math.round(Math.random() * canvas.height),
            rad = Math.ceil(Math.random() * (maxRadius - minRadius)) + minRadius;

        //adds the random circle to the array
        circles.push(new Circle(x, y, rad));
    }

    //clears canvas
    c.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    //redraws ALL circles
    for (let i in circles) {
        circles[i].draw();
    }
}

onDataSubmit();
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1280px;
  margin: auto;
  margin-right: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
}

#dataContainer {
  height: 100%;
  width: 20%;
  padding: 5px;
}

#dataContainer>* {
  padding: 15px;
}

#dataForm {
  max-width: 200px;
  display: grid;
}

#dataForm>* {
  margin-top: 5px;
  width: 100%;
}

.center {
  margin: auto;
}

#stage {
  margin: 5px;
  width: 80%;
  height: 97vh;
}
```

```html
  <div id='wrapper'>
    <!-- form containter -->
    <div id='dataContainer'>
      <h3>Data</h3>

      <form id='dataForm' method='post'>
        <label for='type'>Type:</label>
        <select id='type' name='type'>
          <option value='random' selected>Random</option>
          <option value='order'>Order</option>
          <option value='agar'>Agario</option>
        </select>

        <label for='min'>Min-Radius:</label>
        <input id='dataMinRad' name='min' type='number' value='1' min='0'>

        <label for='max'>Max-Radius:</label>
        <input id='dataMaxRad' name='max' type='number' value='100'>

        <label for='interval'>Phase Interval:</label>
        <input id='phaseInterval' name='interval' type='number' value='1' min='1'>

        <button type='submit' id='dataSubmit' class='center'>Load</submit>
            </form>
        </div>

        <!-- canvas container-->
        <div id='stage'>
            <canvas id='myCanvas'></canvas>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: You should use a simple weighted average instead.

Comment: @catgirlkelly and how would I actually calculate that? I haven't taken stats yet lol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the question is given two overlapping circles find a new circle that represents the merged circles and has an area equal to the sum of the original circles.

For the center of this new circle, one choice is to find the center of mass of the two original circles. If you have two masses of masses m1, m2 and positions (x1,y1), (x2,y2) then the center of mass of the whole system would be

m1/(m1+m2) (x1,y1) + m2/(m1+m2) (x2,y2)

In this case, the center of mass will be

r1^2/(r1^2+r2^2) (x1,y1) + r2^2/(r1^2+r2^2) (x2,y2)

For circles with radii r1, r2 then the masses will be proportional to pi r1^2 + pi r2^2. Hence, the radius of the circle will be sqrt(r1^2+r2^2).

Comment: Not sure what the (x1, y1) and (x2, y2) are for in the calculation, but center of mass is exactly what I wanted. Thanks!

Comment: The (x1,y1) and (x2,y2) are the centres of the two circles.

Comment: How would that be simplified though? Maybe I don't know some a math technique that you know.

Comment: First calculate the common term, d=r1^2+r2^2, find multipliers n1=r1^2/d, n2=r2^2/d.
Now the centre of new circle will be x=n1*x1 + n2*x2, y=n1*y1 + n2*y2.

Answer (score 1):

If you can get the center point coordinates and radius, you can draw this new circle
like this:[image]

And about extract a root √ you can use this:

```js
var xxxx = Math.pow(your target here,2);
```

Update my answer:

[image]

Comment: Yup, exactly how I did it at first. But the result of using midpoint is really weird when you have a huuge circle and a small circle generates on an edge. I feel like naturally that a bigger circle should "weight" more than a smaller one. Any thoughts?

Comment: How about this: X = (x1+x2)*r2/(r1+r2)    Use the scale of the radius to determine the coordinates of its new center

Comment: Oh i get what you mean, let me think for a while..

Comment: I updated my answer maybe can help you